# DEBIAN - How to clean known wifi interface list

Tags: drivers, network-interface, wlan

I've changed my PCI wireless cards several times, and the wlan# interface numbers keep increasing by one. To be more specific, the first wifi interface name was wlan0, after removing that card and installing new one to same slot, the interface name became wlan1 after another one it became wlan2 and so on.

I've been wondering how to clean this cache and make the last connected driver wifi interface name wlan0 ?

Thank you

Comment: you can just the name of yoru current interface you can find what you need here [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @Kingofkech thank you, I found the entries at -> /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Found the entries at  `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`